# Type Casting C++

Tags: c++, casting

see the following code:

```
void simple_dynamic_casts( )
{
  AB  ab;

  B*  bp  = (B*)&ab;  // cast needed to break protection
  A*  ap  = &ab;      // public derivation, no cast needed

  AB& abr = dynamic_cast<AB&>(*bp);  // succeeds

  ap = dynamic_cast<A*>(bp);         assert( ap != NULL );
  bp = dynamic_cast<B*>(ap);         assert( bp == NULL );
  ap = dynamic_cast<A*>(&abr);       assert( ap != NULL );
  bp = dynamic_cast<B*>(&abr);       assert( bp == NULL );
}
```

code taken from [here](http://web.mit.edu/sunsoft_v5.1/www/c-plusplus/c++_ug/Cast.new.doc.html)

will this work

```
ap = &abr;
```

why does the code use a dynamic cast here. i have not tried to compile this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They use `dynamic_cast` to show what it does. So, that's the answer to your "why" question.

Otherwise, the explanations given at that web page are **incorrect**. The resource you are trying to use is either heavily outdated or tied to some specific, poor-quality compiler. The words "The emerging C++ standard..." at the top of the page are a dead giveaway. C++ standard became reality 11 years ago. (Meaning that site is not a good resource for C++ in general and on `dynamic_cast` in particular, if that's what you are looking for.)

Here are their class definitions

```
class A          { public: virtual void f( ); };
class B          { public: virtual void g( ); };
class AB :       public virtual A, private B { };
```

The cast

```
AB& abr = dynamic_cast<AB&>(*bp); // they say: succeeds
```

will *not* succeed. It will throw a `bad_cast` exception, since `B` is not a public base class of `AB`. `dynamic_cast` cannot be used to break protection in downcasts.

The cast

```
bp = dynamic_cast<B*>(&abr);
```

will not even compile, since illegal *upcasts* (breaking protection) are rejected *at compile time* even by `dynamic_cast` (i.e. the code is ill-formed). Note, that `dynamic_cast` does nothing special in this case. With upcasts, `dynamic_cast` is equivalent to `static_cast` or to no-cast-at-all. The above cast will not compile because `B` is a private base. The authors seem to incorrectly assume that `dynamic_cast` should return null-pointer in this case.

As for `ap = &abr` - yes it will work. There's nothing wrong with it, as long a `A` is a public base of `AB`.

Comment: well bp = dynamic_cast<B*>(ap) does compile. however assert fails.

Comment: Oops... That cast should not have been included. It is a cross-cast, not an upcast. I fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. A pointer to a class can always be implicitly converted to a pointer to a public base class; in this case, you're converting from `AB*` to `A*`. A `dynamic_cast` is allowed, but not required.

It's no different to the second conversion (`A*  ap  = &ab;`).

The code uses a `dynamic_cast` to illustrate how that works.

Answer (score 0):

> why does the code use a dynamic cast here.

The `dynamic_cast` operator allows you to check if a cast is valid at runtime.  If it is not, it will return `null` (hence the `assert()` calls).

> will this work

Try it and see... :)